# notifyDataSetChanged() с любого места программы

Tags: android

С помощью notifyDataSetChanged(); можно обновить список. Но этот метод визывается только из адаптера, а мне нужно его вызивать из других мест, как это можно реализовать?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = 1;   if(data.get(position).getId().equals(SinglTon.poss)){viewType=2;}
    return viewType;
}


if(getItemViewType(i)==2){

         @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder ,final int i ) {   VH0.rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9AC5FF"));

                    ...
                }
```

Comment: Если Вы каким-то образом изменили набор данных в адаптере то в этом же месте у Вас однозначно есть доступ к адаптеру и соответственно к нужному Вам методу. Опишите более конкретно  Вашу проблему.

Comment: Реализовую что то вроде мп3 плеера. При нажатии на пункт он выделяется. Реализовано примерно следующим образом в getItemViewType(int p) реализовуется проверка if(id_music==now_play){} now_play static переменная в которую заносится id песни при воспроизведении и обновляется адаптер. Вроде все работает, но допустим если я переключаются песню кнопкой вперёд то к адаптеру доступа нет. Может я вообще не правильно делаю, просто мне кажется, что это самая простая реализация

Comment: В вашем случае будет уместно использовать [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/). Подписывайте на событие в вашем фрагменте/активити и отправляете это событие по нажатию на кнопку "вперед".

Comment: Вообщем с помощью Otto добился отправки сообщения в адаптер @Subscribe
 public void getMessage(String s) {   
  Toast.makeText(ctx , s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  this.notifyDataSetChanged();
 } toast работает а адаптер обновляется не хочет. В чем проблема?

Comment: А Вы уверены что набор данных в этот момент уже изменился?

Comment: Да, так как если прокрутить список вниз и вернуть назад он обновляется

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос методы из адаптера: getView и getItem (если он реализован)

Comment: Добавив код........

Comment: Наверное лучше весь адаптер, по тем методам что вы добавили нет возможности определить проблему

Comment: Кажется нашёл в чем проблема. У меня по логике приложения список отображается в двух местах одновременно, на главном экране и в нижнем баре. И вот в том, который я создаю последним все нормально обновляется.

Comment: Возможно как то обновлять оба адаптера(насколько я понимаю первого уже нет в памяти)

Answer (score 2):

`notifyDataSetChanged` - метод адаптера. Адаптер принадлежит `ListView` или его аналогам (`RecyclerView`, `GridView` etc). Для его получения у них есть геттеры - `getAdapter`. Т.е. вы можете получить к адаптеру доступ везде, где у вас есть доступ к этим виджетам.

Если же вы хотите иметь доступ к этому методу вообще отовсюду, то вам надо использовать к-л библиотеку для рассылки сообщений. Например `Otto`, `EventBus`. Также можно использовать библиотеку `RxJava` (`RxAndroid`) в качестве системы рассылки сообщений.

Comment: Каким образом RxAndroid относится к рассылке сообщений?

Comment: @StasLelyuk, ну, там можно подписаться на излучателя сообщений и их получать. Получается система сообщений. Во всяком случае создатели `Otto` так считают.

Comment: Дайте ссылку пожалуйста, интересно посмотреть как square называет RxAndroid системой рассылки сообщений

Comment: @StasLelyuk, https://github.com/square/otto#deprecated

Comment: Ну Вы конечно выдернули из контекста название RxAndroid. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @StasLelyuk, я не очень понимаю суть ваших претензий(

Comment: Суть моих претензий заключается в том что Вы уровняли rxjava с 2мя event bus библиотеками. Любой новичок может сделать неправильный вывод относительно rxjava.

Comment: @StasLelyuk, ага. Я несколько исправил ответ - так лучше стало?..

Comment: Да, отлично. Спасибо.